# Dask now requiring `pydev_umd`?

Tags: python, dask

I just upgraded to macOS Monterey and am trying to run Dask/Python code that ran last week on macOS Catalina. I've removed and recreated my `conda` environment from the `YAML` file. I've also upgraded the Python to version 3.9.7 for Monterey. Now I get the following error trying to run on my local machine from the Dask worker process.

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to deserialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 111, in loads
    return msgpack.loads(
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 194, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 103, in _decode_default
    return merge_and_deserialize(
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 488, in merge_and_deserialize
    return deserialize(header, merged_frames, deserializers=deserializers)
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 401, in deserialize
    deserialize(
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 417, in deserialize
    return loads(header, frames)
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 96, in pickle_loads
    return pickle.loads(x, buffers=new)
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 75, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydev_umd'
```

Seems like a problem in the latest Dask or something else. Here's the `environment.yml`:

```
name: SpikedTensor
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - dask
  - sqlalchemy
  - pysqlite3
  - pg8000
  - google-api-python-client
  - google-cloud-sdk
  - cloud-sql-python-connector
  - blas[build=mkl]
  - pip
  - pip:
    - dask-saturn>=0.3.0
prefix: /Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/SpikedTensor
```

This is a pretty anodyne configuration. The error feels like a dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

THis seems to run from the console and not from within PyCharm. Hence, I'll ping their support and report back their resolution.

Comment: this seems like a comment and not an answer. also, if this is running fine in the console but not pycharm this seems like an issue with your pycharm configuration, not a dask issue at all. are you sure both your main thread and the dask workers are using the conda env you set up?